# Groundoverlay osmdroid high zoom level

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I need to implement a ground overlay(an indoor floor maps of abuilding) that I can zoom into at a very high level. I am quite new to osmdroid and android maps development.

Google maps limited the zoom to level 21 so I used osmdroid instead. Osmdroid bonus pack also has a similar implementation of a groundoverlay that i can place on the right coordinates.

Problem is even though i can set the groundoverlay at the right coordinates and enable the mapview to have max zoom of 29. Everytime I zoom beyond a certain level the groundoverlay can be seen to zoom in while pinch(zoom gesture with fingers) but zooms out or readjusts the image back to a certain zoom level after i lift the fingers.

I donot require any tilesource to work with osmdroid so for complementary i have given a private tilesource which it fails to load but i can see my groundoverlay.
`ITileSource aTileSource = new XYTileSource("private", 0, 29, 256, ".png",             new String[] {});`

I have tried to change the tilesize to 512 and 1024. I couldnt see any changes to the behaviour. The reason I am asking this question is while i can see osmdroid succesffuky zoom in to the required level, i want it to stay there and not snap back or readjust the image.